# Does Rails `with_lock` block reads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, locking

Suppose I have an `Article` that I want to perform some changes on.

If I use `with_lock`, will it block other processes from reading that row in the `Articles` table?

E.g.

```
 @article = Article.find(1)
 Article.with_lock
   #do something
 end

 # In another process
 @article = Article.find(1) # will this lookup be blocked by the first process?
```

Answer (score 26):

Per [the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html), it does a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` by default.

A `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on a row does *not* block other sessions from reading the row. It only blocks other sessions from obtaining a `FOR UPDATE` (write) or `FOR SHARE` (read) lock on the row. The row remains normally readable to sessions that do a `SELECT` without any `FOR UPDATE` or `FOR SHARE` clause.

So in this case, you'd need to `find` the row, then do a `lock('FOR SHARE')` on it if you wanted to be sure nobody else had a `FOR UPDATE` lock on it.

For more detail see [the PostgreSQL documentation on explicit locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-locking.html).